# Manually stop a module from loading in NesJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a clustered version of Node running. If one node does not fulfill some condition (database) in some time (seconds), I want to be able to not stop the node, but only the Nest module concerned.

For this logic, I'm adding `onModuleInit`, from there, if condition is not met I can `throw new Error()`, but then the whole node is stopped.

I simply would like to stop this module and let the app start normally without.

I have tried injecting `private moduleRef: ModuleRef`, having this object I couldn't find any API to crash the module itself instead of throwing an Error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you just can't stop a module from being loaded. That's not a feature.